# Add items to the Eclipse toolbar

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created a sample Eclipse plugin project where I need to add an multiple items to the same item in the menu and toolbar. I succeeded with adding item to items in menu bar, but when I tried to add items to item in toolbar - none of them is working for me.

How can I add the items to the existing item in the toolbar?

Here is my `plugin.xml` code:

```
<plugin>

<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <category
        name="Sample Category"
        id="com.sample.example.commands.category">
  </category>
  <command
        name="Sample Command"
        categoryId="com.sample.example.commands.category"
        id="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand">
  </command>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        commandId="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand"
        class="com.sample.example.handlers.SampleHandler">
  </handler>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        commandId="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window"
        sequence="M1+6"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration">
  </key>
</extension>
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
     <menu
           label="Sample Menu"
           mnemonic="M"
           id="com.sample.example.menus.sampleMenu">
        <command
              commandId="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand"
              mnemonic="S"
              id="com.sample.example.menus.sampleCommand">
        </command>
        <menu
           label="Sample Menu2"
           mnemonic="M"
           id="com.sample.example.menus.sampleMenu2">
        <command
              commandId="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand"
              mnemonic="S"
              id="com.sample.example.menus.sampleCommand2">
        </command>
     </menu>
     </menu>
   </menuContribution>
   <menuContribution
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
     <toolbar
           id="com.sample.example.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
        <command
              commandId="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand"
              icon="icons/sample.gif"
              tooltip="Say hello world"
              id="com.sample.example.toolbars.sampleCommand">
        </command>
     </toolbar>
  </menuContribution>
      </extension>

  </plugin>
```

I tried adding the following code to the xml, but also it doesn't worked for me.

```
<menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand?after=additions">
        <command
              commandId="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand"
              id="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand1">
        </command>
  </menuContribution>
```

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use? 3.x or 4.x?

Answer (score 2):

I missed out style="pulldown". Now its working fine.
Here is the working code:

```
<menuContribution
    locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
 <toolbar
       id="com.sample.example.toolbars.sampleToolbar">
    <command
          commandId="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand"
          icon="icons/sample.gif"
          tooltip="Say hello world"
          style="pulldown"
          id="com.sample.example.toolbars.sampleCommand">
    </command>
 </toolbar>
</menuContribution>
<menuContribution
    locationURI="menu:com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand?after=additions">
    <command
          commandId="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand"
          style="push"
          id="com.sample.example.commands.sampleCommand1">
    </command>
</menuContribution>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add the missing information there. It is unclear where the "style=pulldown" should go.

Comment: Hi! Did you know that you should mark your own answer as "Accepted" if it solves your problem? That makes it more visible to others that there is a solution already. See the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.